# Display title on material-ui DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to display a title to the DatePicker dialog. This is what I have so far:

[image]

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

function BasicDatePicker(props) {
const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

return (
    <Fragment>
        <DatePicker
            label="Basic example"
            value={selectedDate}
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            animateYearScrolling
        />
    );
}
```

I want it to look something like this?

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In material-UI DatePicker v3, there is no field to add a title as you need.
But in v4, Instead of using "DatePicker" component you have to use "MobileDatePicker".

In, "MobileDatePicker" there is a label field to add a title in your calendar.

Find the working [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-torvalds-tgmvh?file=/src/demo.tsx)